# Ubuntu 13.04 - When maximized, Window title blocks the maximize, minimize, and close buttons

Tags: unity, gnome, titlebar

You can access the menu bar when you bring your cursor up to the top (as in the first image), but when I move it over to the X button to close the program or the maximize or minimize buttons, the title blocks it (in the second image). Is there any way to stop this from happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't happen. It looks like a bug, the buttons stay visible when I'm hovering them. Do they re-appear if you hover out of the title bar and come back over the buttons?
Maybe you should open a bug for Unity on Launchpad.

Edit: Another possibility is that the window is not really maximised, and your title bar goes in fact behind the Unity panel, but it doesn't seem to be the fact here (you have the "un-maximize" icon, not the "maximize" one).

Comment: It fixed itself after restarting, but thanks!